# Discussion of range of cos theta and sin theta

Tags: trigonometry

Is this a printing error or $\cos\theta$ cannot be equal to $1$ and $-1$?

[image]

Text from image:

> $$-1\le\sin\theta\le1;\ \ \ \ \ \ \ -1<\cos\theta<1\ \ \ \forall\theta\in\Bbb R$$

Comment: It's a typo, the inequalities should be $\le$. For example, $\cos 0 = 1$.

Comment: The “$\le$” in “$-1\le \sin\theta$” has the “or equal to” part faded, so maybe the ink faded for the typos?

Answer (score 0):

It’s most likely a typo; the cosine can be $1$ and $-1$ just like the sine can (as it’s a shifted version of the sine).

The only case I can think of where this would be right is if $R$ stands not for $\mathbb R$ here but for some subset, for instance $R=\mathbb R\setminus\{n\pi\mid n\in\mathbb Z\}$.